# How to use cleveref names as theorem names with thmtools

Tags: babel, cleveref, amsthm, thmtools

I'm trying to setup a few theorem-like environments with `thmtools`, making it work with `cleverer` while trying to stay compatible with different languages.

If I load `cleveref` after `thmtools` it seems to work very well with translated cross-references coming out from the `\cref` command. It seems that a combination of `babel` and `cleveref` already knows how to translate "theorem", "lemma", and "definition" to my language (who is providing the translation and how?).

However, the same is not true with the environment *names*, so I have to somehow provide a translated string to the `name=` option of `\declaretheorem`. I've found in the `cleveref` manual that there are some macros that provide the names used by the package, such as `\cref@theorem@name`, and I'm trying to use them. It all worked well when I was using `amsthm`, but if I load `thmtools` I get an inexplicable error message.

The following minimal example should show the problem:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} % Comment this line and it works
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{theorem}{\cref@theorem@name}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Let ABC be a triangle. If it hits your head it will hurt\ldots
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the code above I get the error:

```
./mwe.tex:10: Undefined control sequence. [\makeatother]
```

Note, in the code above I'm using `\newtheorem` only to make the example work if you comment the `\usepackage{thmtools}` line. The same problem happens if I use `\declaretheorem` (which of course is not available without `thmtools`).

What is happening here?

P.S: I'm not just writing "Teorema" as the theorem name because I'm writing a class file and I want to stay compatible with multiple languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chicken or egg? `;-)`

`\cref@theorem@name` is not yet defined when `\newtheorem` is issued. Solution: use `\noexpand`.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} % Comment this line and it works
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem{theorem}{\noexpand\cref@theorem@name}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{test}
Let ABC be a triangle. If it hits your head it will hurt\ldots
\end{theorem}

\cref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make this compatible with `\declaretheorem` you have to add a couple of `\noexpand`'s in front of the symbolic name.

Here's a less heavy way:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} % Comment this line and it works
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\dtname}[1]{%
  \expandafter\noexpand
  \expandafter\noexpand
  \expandafter\noexpand
  \csname cref@#1@name\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\ntname}[1]{%
  \expandafter\noexpand
  \csname cref@#1@name\endcsname
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\ntname{theorem}}

\declaretheorem[name=\dtname{lemma}]{lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{tl}
$0\ne 1$
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}\label{test}
Sia $ABC$ un triangolo. Se ti piglia in testa ti farà male.
\end{theorem}

Il \cref{test} e il \cref{tl} sono importanti.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but the solution works for `\newtheorem` but not for `\declaretheorem`. I've tried `\declaretheorem[name=\noexpand\cref@theorem@name]{theorem}` and it doesn't work with the same error message. Any idea?

Comment: @gigabytes You have to suppress two expansions: `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\cref@theorem@name`